# Populating NSRectPointer in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsrect

I'm translating some Objective-C code I got from a book to Swift. The code in question is a custom implementation of an `NSTextContainer` method:

```
-(NSRect)lineFragmentRectForProposedRect:(NSRect)proposedRect
                          sweepDirection:(NSLineSweepDirection)sweepDirection
                       movementDirection:(NSLineMovementDirection)movementDirection
                           remainingRect:(NSRectPointer)remainingRect
{

 // ... now set value of the struct pointed at by NSRectPointer
 *remainingRect = NSRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50);

 //...
 return mainRect;
}
```

I struggling to replicate this in Swift - no matter what I try I keep getting told that I can't assign to a `let` variable.

Comment: I can't pass in anything - the method is called by *Cocoa*, hence the arguments are also provided by *Cocoa*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSRectPointer` is defined as

```
public typealias NSRectPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<NSRect>
```

and `UnsafeMutablePointer` has a

```
/// Access the underlying raw memory, getting and setting values.
public var memory: Memory { get nonmutating set }
```

property, therefore the Swift equivalent of the Objective-C code

```
*remainingRect = NSRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50);
```

should be

```
remainingRect.memory = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 100, 50)
```

Comment: Thanks - I was trying to use ``puts``, and just glossed over ``memory``.